# Gui application halting on OSX when left unattended

Tags: java, macos, osx-mavericks

My (java based) Gui application processes digital music files, and is designed so it can be left unattended. I have noticed that if I leave it running overnight on my OSX Mavericks computer that it stops shortly after I leave it, only restarting when I touch the keybaord in the morning.

How can I prevent this, I do not have the same problem running the application on a Windows 8 machine.

Comment: A bit of a shot in the dark since we have no idea what code you have, but could it be that you are referencing a resource which has a different connection string on OSX and Windows 8?

Comment: Do you have this problem as well with non-Java applications? Sounds like your computer just goes to sleep. If so, that's not a Java question but an OSX question.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt maybe I don't know that's why Ive tagged with both. I just have default settings, the screen goes off but does that mean its sleeping, why would it sleep when something is running in the foreground ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your app in the Finder and "Get Info" and then check "Disable App Nap"…
[See the Apple Developer notes for Mavericks for more info](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_9.html)

Comment: Yes it does seem to be AppNap